# Membership Directory Profile Error

Tags: profile, joomla

I am running CiviCRM 4.6.13 on Joomla 3.4.8.

I have created a membership directory following the wiki direction (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Creating+a+website+member+directory).

At first, it worked just fine when previewed with "Use Profile-Listings Mode." Then I created a menu item to view the profile as a list in Joomla (Profile View Page with my Membership Directory profile selected).

When I click on the link I get an error "Permission Denied You do not have permission to view this contact record." And under that is a link "Back to Listings".

It seems that it is trying to take me to a specific individual record, and giving me an error based on that. But when I click on "Back to Listings" it actually takes me to the Profile listing just as I intend (except without the initial error). (However, at that time, it tells me "No fields in this Profile have been configured as searchable" even though almost all the fields have been set as searchable.)

The secondary problem is annoying, but why am I being taken to a page that says "Permission Denied You do not have permission to view this contact record." instead of to the profile list?

I can provide temporary credentials if you want to see the problem in action.